# Array filling that users inputs with Method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, pass-by-reference

i need your help for my project. I'm writing an program which show students informations that users fills previously. this is about how much did i learn the methods. I already wrote a program with out methods. But when i write same things with method i encountered with pass by reference... i am filling the 0. index but when i fill the 1. index, 0. index became a null. I try everything but i cannot solve this problem i think thats about my returns... here is the code can you help me with basically way coz as you can see my Java language level is beginner:)  ;

```
//=========================================================== Methods 
  public static void record(String x, int y)
   String[] stringArray = new String[100];
   stringArray[y] = x;
   return stringArray;
   }
public static double[] record(double x, int y){
double[] doubleArray = new double[100];
doubleArray[y] = x;
return doubleArray;
}
```

and my option ;

```
 case 1:  {
    System.out.println("** Recording a new student");
    System.out.println("*** Please use lower case");
    in.nextLine(); // for solve skipping 

    System.out.print("Enter Student Name and Surname: ");
    String namex = in.nextLine();
    name=record(namex,accountNumber);


    System.out.print("Enter Student Gender(m/f): ");
    String genderx = in.nextLine();
    gender=record(genderx,accountNumber);

    System.out.print("Enter Student Number: ");
    String studentNox = in.nextLine();
    studentNo=record(studentNox,accountNumber);


    System.out.print("Enter Student GPA: "); // i dont use method here for testing
    gpa[accountNumber] = in.nextDouble();


    accountNumber++;


    System.out.println("New Student Recorded. There are ["+accountNumber+"] students in system.");
    System.out.println("");
  }break;
```

Comment: That `void` method returning a String Array looks strange in several ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're initializing the array every time you put something inside it:

```
String[] stringArray = new String[100];

double[] doubleArray = new double[100];
```

You must make sure that initialization of these arrays happens just *once* in your application, probably when declaring these static arrays. Knowing that, your `record` methods should look like (based on your code):

```
public static void record(String x, int y)
    stringArray[y] = x;
}

public static void record(double x, int y) {
    doubleArray[y] = x;
}
```

Also, as basic knowledge, Java **never** passes by reference, it only pass by value. More info here: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197)

Comment: You're right , it is pass-by-value. my fault... so, i change my code with these and i have stringArray named array in my main but my compile giving an error for stringArray "...cannot be resolved to a variable" am i need more definiton for these arrays?

Comment: @GökhanNas From your actual code in your question, I can't provide a solution to your new problem.